# Sortable list with droppable item inside hover placeholder issue

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-ui-sortable, placeholder, droppable

I have a sortable list with an droppable item inside what needs to be sorted too.
When you drag an item next the drop item, where the placeholder is showing up, the drop item is still active on the placeholder.

A simple Fiddle is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bRbyW/108/)

```
    $("#item-list").sortable();

$(".container").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(this).append(dropped.clone().removeAttr('style').removeClass("item").addClass("item-container"));
        dropped.remove();
    }
});
```

Is there already an solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want `item container` class to be sortable use `cancel`

```
$("#item-list").sortable({
  cancel: ".item.container"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution http://jsfiddle.net/bRbyW/110/

```js
$("#item-list").sortable();

$(".container").droppable({
    accept: ".item",
    beforeStop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).html();
    },
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        if($(droppedOn)[0].innerHTML.indexOf('<div') < 0)
         $(droppedOn)[0].innerHTML = '';
  $(this).append(dropped.clone().removeAttr('style').removeClass("item").addClass("item-container"));
        
        dropped.remove();
    }
});
```

```css
.item {
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px dashed red;
    margin:10px 0;
    cursor:move;
}
.container {
    height:150px;
    border:1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="item-list">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item container">dropbox but still sortable</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Shiladitya, I have a feeling you're almost there, however if I'm just sorting around the dropbox, theyre still being dropped

Answer (score 0):

Wow, i'm answering my own question!

The solution is, put this in your sortable option list:

```
refreshPositions: true
```

That works like a charm!

Thx everybody!